# Is possible to use typeORM with Druid?

Tags: typeorm, druid

Currently I cannot find any information on a Node compatiable ORM for working with druid.

Druid is not officially supported by typeORM.

Druid takes sql("Druid SQL") so hypothetically, I should be able to output the raw sql queries to druid, correct?

Answer (score 0):

I've not seen typeORM directly - rather it's super common for apps to query the Apache Calcite-powered SQL API directly:
https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/querying/sql.html

Some people build an additional layer with application logic on top first - e.g. what Target have done.
https://imply.io/virtual-druid-summit/enterprise-scale-analytics-platform-powered-by-druid-at-target

Note the bit on NULL handling in case that's important to ya :) https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/querying/sql.html#null-values